Mongo Compass find elements containing a list where properties match
I can't find anywhere in mongo documentation how to do this kind of query:
I've got a collection containing lots of objects, some of which have the type I want (let's call it "Graph"). They contain a property that contains nodes and edges. I'm trying to find every Graph object that contains at least two edges that have the same end node and the same value for a specific property (let's call it type).
So my data looks something like this:
[{
  type: "Graph",
  name: "Graph A",
  graph: {
    nodes: [
      { id: 1},
      { id: 2},
      { id: 3}
    ],
    edges: [
      { id: 4, type: "A", start: 1, end: 3 },
      { id: 5, type: "A", start: 2, end: 3 }
    ]
  }
},
{
  type: "Graph",
  name: "Graph B",
  graph: {
    nodes: [
      { id: 1},
      { id: 2},
      { id: 3},
      { id: 4}
    ],
    edges: [
      { id: 5, type: "A", start: 1, end: 3 },
      { id: 6, type: "B", start: 2, end: 3 },
      { id: 7, type: "A", start: 2, end: 4 }
    ]
  }
}]

I'm looking for a query that gives me Graph A but not Graph B, because Graph A contains two edges where both type and end match, and Graph B doesn't.
Edit: Best option I've been able to find so far, is a $where containing a $function, but I can't get it to work. It also doesn't select on { type: "Graph" } yet.
{ $where: { $function: {
  body: function(edges) {
    return edges.some(a => edges.some(b => a!==b && a.type === b.type && a.end === b.end));
  },
  args: [ "$graph.edges" ],
  lang: "js"
} } }


Your sample data are not valid json documents. Are graph.nodes and graph.edges array fields? Please provide valid sample json documents.

1. Since you want to match on any type having two end's, and not specifically, 'A' or 'B', I don't think this can be done in a simple find() query. You'll need an aggregation pipeline. 2. Do you want the actual objects/documents or just their id's? 3. Is it safe to assume type is always a string and end is always a number? 4. Also, there are some typos in your example - edges and nodes should be an array of objects, nodes: [ { id: 1}, { id: 2} ] but you've used curly braces: nodes: { { id: 1}, { id: 2} }.

@ray You're absolutely right. I wrote the arrays incorrectly. I've fixed it now.

@aneroid Yes, for this purpose it's safe to assume type is always a string and end is always a number. It's a very simplified version of the real data of course.
I'll see if I can figure out how to create an aggregation pipeline in Compass. The only examples I've seen so far are in code.

There's a "tab" called Aggregations and then select "Text" which lets you create pipelines in stages and see input/output samples from your collection.

I've added my best attempt so far, using javascript. I understand it's possible to use javascript in a query, and that probably sounds like my best option, but I can't get it to work.

Btw, since I said "You'll need an aggregation pipeline" - that's not actually true. I've updated my answer to do the same thing with a find query. But it's VERY ugly and I do not recommend using it that way.

I'm too new to MongoDB to have strong opinions on the matter. Are aggregation pipelines generally the preferred way to handle these sort of cases?


$match on type=Graph

$map each edge to a string in the form "<edge.type>|<edge.end>".

If type is always a string and end is always a number and neither are null, then the result is an array like ["A|3", "A|3"] or ["A|3", "B|3", "A|4"].
The pipe | separator is optional, it could even be like ["A3", "A3"] or ["A3", "B3", "A4"].


$filter the array of strings to exclude any null values. If the 'type' or 'edge' is null or missing, the resulting concatenation is null. So this will remove those entries before proceeding.

Updated the pipeline based on your comment about missing 'type'.
this can also be done outside the $map stage above but I prefer keeping things separate.


Use $setIntersection to convert that array into a set - actually an array of unique values, by intersecting (or union) with itself.

This is why I'm converting each type & edge into a single string - they can be used as values in a Set.


If there is a repetition of type|end ie. occurred more than once ie "at least two", then the original array and its "set" of unique value would have different lengths; by checking $size.


db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { type: "Graph" } },
  {
    $set: {
      allTypeEnds: {
        $map: {
          input: "$graph.edges",
          in: {
            $concat: ["$$this.type", "|", { $toString: "$$this.end" } ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      allTypeEnds: {
        $filter: { input: "$allTypeEnds", cond: "$$this" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          { $size: "$allTypeEnds" },
          { $size: { $setIntersection: ["$allTypeEnds", "$allTypeEnds"] } }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "allTypeEnds" }
])

Updated Mongo Playground - note the multiple edges added in the data for Graph B with {end: 3} and no type field; and it won't be in the results.

Btw, that aggregation pipeline could be turned into a find query but it's ugly and really hard to modify later; I DO NOT RECOMMEND writing it like this, just showing that it's possible.
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      { type: "Graph" },
      {
        $ne: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$graph.edges",
                    in: {
                      $concat: ["$$this.type", "|", { $toString: "$$this.end" }]
                    }
                  }
                },
                cond: "$$this"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $size: {
              $setIntersection: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$graph.edges",
                        in: {
                          $concat: ["$$this.type", "|", { $toString: "$$this.end" }]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    cond: "$$this"
                  }
                },
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$graph.edges",
                        in: {
                          $concat: ["$$this.type", "|", { $toString: "$$this.end" }]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    cond: "$$this"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})

Mongo Playground demo of bad way to write this

Nice! This seems to work perfectly on the test data. It doesn't quite seem to work on my actual data, so I think I messed something up, but I can probably figure that out for myself. Thanks!

Ah, I realize the "type" property doesn't always exist. Is there a way to skip the edges where it doesn't exist? I could check on a hard value on another property could guarantee that it does exist.

Add a $filter step with allTypeEnds before the map stage and then use that filtered allTypeEnds in the $map stage, instead of $graph.edges.

@mcv I've updated the answer to include a filter to ignore nulls. The filter assumes type should be a truthy value (non-empty string, not null, not undefined, etc.)

I've figured out my own solution to the type=null issue by adding a filter on a third property to the input of the $map, but I'll definitely study both of your solutions. Thanks for the incredible help.

One advantage of the 'uglier' .find solution is that it doesn't add a temporary property to the objects in the database, which I think the aggregation pipeline does. Is that something that's common for MongoDB?

The 'allTypeEnds' property is not in the database. It only exists in the aggregation pipeline, in-memory (sort of). Even if it was in the agg result, it wouldn't be in the database - since I'm not writing it to the DB with $merge or $out as the last stage. We're talking about the Aggregation stage $set for an aggregation pipeline. The Update operator $set is different, that one actually writes to the DB of course.

That makes more sense. The explicit removal in the final line made me think it was in the db itself. Thanks for clearing that up.

And wrt "Is that something that's common for MongoDB?" - adding fields in Aggregation Pipelines? Yes, that's very common, you'll see many of those on StackOverflow. Most non-trivial aggregation pipelines will set fields in the pipeline, either as necessary for the result or temporarily before un-setting them. Conversely, the find version may or may not calculate the filter+map 3 times - will need to deep-dive into the query plain/explain for that. More importantly, it's unreadable because if the 3rd time was just slightly different from the previous two, would people notice?

Yeah, the find version would really benefit from a way to separate the repetitive part as its own function.
